# System.Net.WebRequest not respecting hosts file

Tags: c#, .net, hosts

Is there a way to get a `System.Net.WebRequest` or `System.Net.WebClient` to respect the `hosts` or `lmhosts` file?

For example: in my hosts file I have:

```
10.0.0.1  www.bing.com
```

When I try to load Bing in a browser (both IE and FF) it fails to load as expected.

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.bing.com")[0]; // 10.0.0.1 
WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.0.1").GetResponse(); // throws exception (expected)
WebRequest.Create("http://www.bing.com/").GetResponse(); // unexpectedly succeeds
```

Similarly:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadString("http://www.bing.com"); //succeeds
```

Why would `System.Net.Dns` respect the hosts file but `System.Net.WebRequest` ignore it? What do I need to change to make the WebRequest respect the hosts file?

Additional Info:

- If I disable IPv6 and set my IPv4 DNS Server to 127.0.0.1, the above code works (fails) as expected. However if I add my normal DNS servers back as alternates, the unexpected behavior resumes.
- I've reproduced this on 3 Win7 and 2 Vista boxes. The only constant is my company's network.
- I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1 and VS2008

**Edit**

Per @Richard Beier's suggestion, I tried out `System.Net` tracing. With tracing **ON** the `WebRequest` fails as it should. However as soon as I turn tracing **OFF** the behavior reverts to the unexpected success. I have reproduced this on the same machines as before in both debug and release mode.

**Edit 2**

This turned out to be the company proxy giving us issues. Our solution was a custom proxy config script for our test machines that had "bing.com" point to DIRECT instead of the default proxy.

Comment: I'm guessing you are working through a proxy in your network.  What does your browser do?

Comment: Both IE and FF behave as expected (attempting to load from the server indicated in the hosts file).

Comment: Have you tried `ipconfig /flushdns` ?

Comment: Yes, and `ipconfig /displaydns` shows the entry in the hosts file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that  @Hans Passant has spotted the issue here.  It looks like you have a proxy setup in IE.

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.bing.com")[0]; // 10.0.0.1
```

This works because you are asking the OS to get the IP addresses for [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com)

```
WebRequest.Create("http://www.bing.com/").GetResponse(); // unexpectedly succeeds
```

This works because you are asking the framework to fetch a path from a server name.   The framework uses the same engine and settings that IE frontend uses and hence if your company has specified by a GPO that you use a company proxy server, it is that proxy server that resolves the IP address for [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com) rather than you.

```
WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.0.1").GetResponse(); // throws exception (expected)
```

This works/fails  because you have asked the framework to fetch you a webpage from a specific server (by IP). Even if you do have a proxy set, this proxy will still not be able to connect to this IP address.

I hope that this helps.

Jonathan

Comment: You're right that I'm behind a company proxy but I'm not sure I follow your logic. I would expect that `WebRequest.Create()` would exhibit identical behavior to IE but it doesn't. Bing.com in IE times out trying to load 10.0.0.1

Comment: Check the web.config to make sure a defaultProxy isn't set up - removing this fixed the above for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VS 2010 on Windows 7, and I can't reproduce this. I made the same hosts-file change and ran the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.bing.com")[0]);             // 10.0.0.1     
var response = WebRequest.Create("http://www.bing.com/").GetResponse(); // * * *
Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

I got an exception on the line marked "* * *". Here's the exception detail:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Data\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 17
  InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
       Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.0.0.1:80
       Source=System
       ErrorCode=10060
```

Maybe it's an issue with an earlier .NET version, that's now fixed in .NET 4 / VS 2010? Which version of .NET are you using?

I also found this [thread](http://dotnet.itags.org/dotnet-tech/290459/) from 2007, where someone else ran into the same problem. There are some good suggestions there, including the following:

- Turn on [system.net tracing](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224040541/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx)
- Work around the problem by using Dns.GetHostAddresses() to resolve it to an IP. Then put the IP in the URL - e.g. "http://10.0.0.1/". That may not be an option for you though.

In the above thread, mariyaatanasova_msft also says: "HttpWebRequest uses Dns.GetHostEntry to resolve the host, so you may get a different result from Dns.GetHostAddresses".

Comment: I'm using VS2008 and 3.5 SP1. `GetHostEntry` gives me the same output as `GetHostAddress`.  I'll look into tracing. Thanks.

Comment: Turned on System.Net tracing per your suggestion. With tracing on, the WebRequest fails as expected. With tracing off it goes back to unexpectedly succeeding. Thoughts?

Comment: That's very strange - I don't have a good answer. Hans Passant and Jonathan Stanton have good points regarding proxies. But if IE uses a proxy and still respects your hosts file, then the hosts file should also override the proxy when using WebRequest.

The only thing I can suggest is to try disabling the proxy anyway, as mwalker's suggests. You could also try a packet sniffer such as Wireshark or Network Monitor to see what's happening on the wire - but I'm not sure that will help. If you see a DNS request for www.bing.com, that confirms it's not using the hosts file, but doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite the default proxy.
HttpWebRequest & WebRequest will set a default proxy if present in Internet Explorer and your file **hosts** will be **bypassed**.

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
```

The following is just an example of code:

```
try
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.bing.com");
   request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
   request.Method = "POST";            
   request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();               
   if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
      //some code here
   }
}
catch (exception e)
{
   //Some other code here
}
```